# How to Create Android Apps in MVC 5(Visual Studio 2013)?

Tags: android, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2013

I have create Android apps in Android studio.but,I Will Need Android Apps create in MVC 5(Visual Studio 2013).I m New to Android in MVC..How can i create Andriod Apps in MVC??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps to set it up:

1. Download the Android SDK.
2. Download the Android NDK.
3. Download Cygwin.
4. Download the Java JDK.
5. Download Visual Studio. (If not already done.)
6. Download vs-android [here](https://github.com/gavinpugh/vs-android).
7. Download Apache Ant.
8. Set environment variables:

(Control Panel > System > Advanced > Environment Variables)

```
ANDROID_HOME = <install_path>\android-sdk
ANDROID_NDK_ROOT = <install_path>\android-ndk
ANT_HOME  = <install_path>\apache-ant
JAVA_HOME = <install_path>\jdk
_JAVA_OPTIONS = -Xms256m -Xmx512m
```

9. Download examples from [here](https://github.com/gavinpugh/vs-android)

Comment: Thanks @Patrick T. !but,I Found Another way  is Xamarin..very Thanks for Answer..

Comment: ok, I am going to check your way, maybe it is easier than mine.

Comment: I m beginner in MVC.No idea how to create android apps in MVC..please tell about better way..